# Yii2 фильтр GridView использовать с creocoder/yii2-taggable?

Tags: php, yii2, gridview

Установил и привязал теги к "Клиентам" по инструкции creocoder/yii2-taggable, всё работает как нужно. Как привязать фильтр к этим тегам в GridView?

view/index

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
     //...
        [
            'attribute' => 'interests',
            'format' => 'html',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                return $data->tagValues;
            },
        ],

    ],
]); ?>
```

и модель поиска (сгенерирована Gii)

```
   $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'full_name', $this->full_name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'phone', $this->phone])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'email', $this->email])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'address', $this->address])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'photo', $this->photo])

        // Как тут отфильтровать по тегам?
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'interests', $this->interests]);

    return $dataProvider;
```

[image: фильтр по интересам(тегам)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решение: Нужно было добавить `innerJoin` к запросу поиска и указать таблицу в фильтре вот так

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Clients::find()->innerJoinWith('interest', true);

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    //...

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'full_name', $this->full_name])
        //...
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'interest.name', $this->interest])

    return $dataProvider;
}
```